# Binding issue on CustomControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I have written a CustomControl on WPF which is simply a ContentControl with a ContentPresenter and a Button.

Here is the control template (located in Themes/Generic.xaml) :

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TestControl}">
    <StackPanel Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        <Button Content="Next" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsNextButtonEnabled}" />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Here is the control code (TestControl.cs) :

```c#
public class TestControl : ContentControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the IsNextButtonEnabled dependency property
    /// </summary>
    public readonly static DependencyProperty IsNextButtonEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsNextButtonEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(TestControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(true)
    );

    static TestControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TestControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TestControl)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value indicating if the Next button of the control is enabled
    /// </summary>
    [BindableAttribute(true)]
    public bool IsNextButtonEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(IsNextButtonEnabledProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsNextButtonEnabledProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

---

I want to bind the value of IsNextButtonEnabled of the TestControl to another control (for example a CheckBox) that is inside the Content of the TestControl itself.

So I did that and it works (when I check or uncheck the CheckBox, the button enables or disables itself correctly):

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:TestControl IsNextButtonEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cb, Path=IsChecked}">
            <CheckBox Name="cb" IsChecked="True" />
        </local:TestControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But what I want to do is to declare my TestControl in a separated xaml file. So I did this but it doesn't work:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:MyTestControl />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MyTestControl.xaml (MyTestControl.cs is not changed) :

```
<local:TestControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.MyTestControl"
                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
                   IsNextButtonEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cb, Path=IsChecked}">
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox Name="cb" IsChecked="True" />
    </Grid>
</local:TestControl>
```

While executing, in the Output window i get this error message :

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=cb'. BindingExpression:Path=IsChecked; DataItem=null; target element is 'MyTestControl' (Name=''); target property is 'IsNextButtonEnabled' (type 'Boolean')

I don't understant my mistake. Did I make something wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing your Xaml so that the Checkbox has the binding?  Meaning, remove the IsNextButtonEnabled= from your TestControl declaration, and add to the CheckBox, IsChecked="{Binding IsNextButtonEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}".  Then make sure the DataContext for CheckBox is set to the TestControl.

Answer (score 2):

try this, bind the `IsChecked` of the checkbox to `IsNextButtonEnabled` property

```
<ContentControl x:Class="WpfStackOverflowSpielWiese.TestControl"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                x:Name="control">

  <Grid>
    <CheckBox Name="cb"
              IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=control, Path=IsNextButtonEnabled}" />
  </Grid>
</ContentControl>
```

code behind

```c#
public partial class TestControl : ContentControl
{
  public TestControl() {
    this.InitializeComponent();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Identifies the IsNextButtonEnabled dependency property
  /// </summary>
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsNextButtonEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IsNextButtonEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(true));

  static TestControl() {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TestControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TestControl)));
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets or sets the value indicating if the Next button of the control is enabled
  /// </summary>
  [Bindable(true)]
  public bool IsNextButtonEnabled {
    get { return (bool)this.GetValue(IsNextButtonEnabledProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(IsNextButtonEnabledProperty, value); }
  }
}
```

hope this helps